# How to bind my platform driver to an ACPI Container device

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, acpi

My Laptop has following SuperIO device in the SSDT Table:

```asl
DefinitionBlock ("", "SSDT", 1, "VENDORx", "TABLEx", 0x00001000)
{
    Device (\_SB.PC00.LPCB.SIO0)
    {
        Name (_HID, EisaId ("PNP0A05") /* Generic Container Device */)
        Name (_UID, "SD28301")
    }
```

This ID claimed by the ACPI container driver but I see in /sys/bus/container/* that there is no driver associated with this device.

I wanted to write a platform driver to attach with this device. I have the following in my driver code:

```c
static const struct acpi_device_id sio_device_ids[] = {
    { "PNP0A05", 0},
    { "", 0}
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(acpi, sio_device_ids);
```

Upon calling `platform_driver_register()`, my driver does not get bound to the SIO device. To see if kernel is even trying to match the `acpi_device_id` entries, I changed PNP0A05 in my kernel code to MHF1234 (custom _HID). Then I inserted an SSDT with a device that had _HID same as `acpi_device_id` in kernel driver like this: `Name (_HID, EisaId ("MHF1234")`. Now, upon inserting my driver, the probe function got called so my driver matched with the ACPI device.

Question: How do I match my driver with PNP0A05 device? I see that the ACPI container driver already detected and added this to /sys but there is no driver bound to it. Any hints to debug would be appreciated.

Comment: @0andriy This driver doesn't seem to call *_driver_register - shouldn't the device have no drivers matched with it then (which is evident from the sysfs topology that there is no driver associated with this device).

Comment: @0andriy This device appears as a folder under /sys/bus/container/devices/PNP050A:05 which doesn't seem to have a driver matched with it. The function that you shared above installs a handler with attach function which should be called when this device is found (which registers the device with the kernel like you mentioned). I guess my question is how do I get my driver to match with this found device as clearly the acpi container driver is only registering the device with kernel, not binding/matching with the device.

Comment: @0andriy Incidentally I found the same definition and came to the same conclusion to not bind to this SIO rather make new nodes under it in ASL and bind to those devices (which I was going to do anyway for child devices). The question still remains unanswered as to why I my driver is not binding to it (my guess being something in kernel preventing it) so I will leave the question open.

Comment: @0andriy I used ACPI driver and it was still unable to bind with PNP0A05 although it did bind with my custom device so at least my driver code was correct. Anyway, can you point me to more information about ACPI Driver method being deprecated? I was planning on going to this route for my actual driver bcz all of my device information is in ACPI so I thought it might be easier to read/organize that data in the driver if I use an ACPI driver. No evidence, only beginner approach..

Comment: @0andriy it cannot be the missing _CRS method as my new custom device doesn't have a _CRS but it does appear in /sys/bus/platform/devices. PNP0A05 doesn't so there must be something else.

Comment: @0andriy Bingo! Now that answers the question and I will gladly accept that. Regarding your question, the goal is to create ACPI device which encapsulates platform configuration (HW attached to SIO under several platforms) and all control methods in ACPI tables provided by BIOS, so that generic device driver (in multiple OSes) reads HW info from ACPI and uses the ACPI methods to control the hardware. Generic SIO driver that only exposes IO Ports and so on is not sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device is being created by the code under [drivers/acpi/container.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/acpi/container.c#L44). However, it's purely ACPI device for now. The platform devices for ACPI ones are created by `acpi_create_platform_device()` which is supposed to be called by `acpi_bus_attach()` (via `acpi_default_enumeration()` because it's not enumerated by parent). However, `container_device_attach()` on success returns positive number, i.e. 1, and `acpi_bus_attach()` skips platform device creation due to [the conditional](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/acpi/scan.c#L2180). That's why it's not being represented as platform device and hence may not be enumerated via platform bus.

Besides that, ACPI specification tells us the following: *PNP0A05 Generic Container Device. A device whose settings are totally controlled by its ACPI resource information, and otherwise **needs no device or bus-specific driver support**. This was originally known as Generic ISA Bus Device. This ID should only be used for containers that do not produce resources for consumption by child devices. Any system resources claimed by a PNP0A05 device’s _CRS object must be consumed by the container itself.*